# Getting hashes of any type of objects in Common Lisp

Tags: hash, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to implement some data structures (like HAMP-hash array mapped trie) in Common Lisp and I need to get 32- or 64-bit hashes of objects which I want to store in these data structures.

I know I can put objects into Common Lisp hash tables (created with `(make-hash-table)`), but I couldn't find a way to get a hash of an object, like `hashCode` of Java or `hash` of Python.  Does Common Lisp have a function like that?  If doesn't, how does CL's standard hash table generate hashes from arbitrary types of objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `sxhash` returns a hash for its argument.  Details: [sxhash](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_sxhash.htm#sxhash).

```
* (sxhash 'fred)
4287909749829334992
* (sxhash 'joe)
23906557261513707
* (sxhash 'fred)
4287909749829334992
```

Comment: great! thanks. it looks like `sxhash` generating 62bit hashes on my 64bit SBCL system.

Comment: The return value of `sxhash` is defined by the standard to be a non-negative fixnum. A good implementation will probably make use of the full range of non-negative fixnums is has.